# Issue in jQuery when version changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Till time we were using jQuery 3.3.1 version. However, as per customer requirement we need to use jQuery 1.1.0 version.
Now when we have started to use the old version it is giving the below error

> Refused to set unsafe header “Connection”

However, we are not setting any headers explicitly in any ajax call. Below is the code example for the same.

```
var val = 'somename';

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Home/Index",
        data: { 'Name': val },
        success: function (data) {

            // success logic

        }
    });
```

This issue is occurring wherever we are making ajax call(GET,POST).
Now we have referred the old jQuery like this

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.1.js" integrity="sha256-WC/UOPCQHWTQbGMlXU192KwqIXZ9Xae1FhfajGhRMj4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Also we are integrating Google Captcha and other payment providers iframe on the page. Is that causing an issue ?

The ajax call works fine if we did not integrate/implement any other things. But If I am loading captcha controls OR payment providers IFrame then it is giving the error

Any help on this appreciated !

Comment: Are you using any api calls or Ajax calls in your IFrame?

Comment: @sony We are rendering the iframe, on submit button of iframe we are calling our ajax method,